# Can you help integrate this Gaussian?

Tags: integration

Mathematica is playing up and I need:

> > $$
> > \int_{0}^{a}\exp\left(-\rho\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{b\sqrt{r}}x^{1/2}-\pi rx+\left(\frac{8br^{2}-5}{6b\sqrt{2}r^{3/2}}\right)x^{3/2}\right)\right)\left(r+x\right)dx\
> > $$

Can anyone help?

Comment: Once again I feel a really naughty disturbance in the force...

Comment: What's the question? Since you are integrating with respect to $x,$ an approximation wrt $x$ makes little sense, and what are the bounds of the integral?

Comment: Basically, can anyone do the integral

Comment: The indefinite integral???

Comment: consider the limits 0 to a, but only the lower limit (at 0) is needed...

Comment: yes, the indefinite integral

Comment: That doesn't even make sense.

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: ive edited the question

Comment: does it make sense now? I just need the integral

Comment: "consider the limits 0 to a, but only the lower limit (at 0) is needed" means that the resulting form would be a function of $a$, but you talk about behavior near $x = 0$. That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can make the substitution $x=u^2,$ which will get rid of the square roots. Second, the integral is not possible in elementary terms. Third, if you want it for $a$ small, just expand the integrand in a power series at zero, and integrate term by term. Fourth, the integral from $0$ to $\infty$ seems hard also. Since I am not exactly sure of what you want, this is all I can offer.